# Impressão em ZEBRA via PHP ZPL

Tags: php, impressão

Estou com um problema, tenho um aplicação em PHP que gera um código zpl que é enviaodo a um servidor que tem uma zebra instalada.
Funciona perfeitamente, o problema é que a impressora é utilizada em outros sistemas e após imprimir através do meu sistema, a impressora desconfigura a etiqueta dos outros sistemas, tamanho, código de barras, fonte, causando transtorno pois para voltar ao normal é necessário reiniciar a impressora.